# with SSHTunnelForwarder function - based way to maintain connection?

Tags: python, mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am adding SSHTunnel logic to an existing python script that makes calls to a mysql database.  I was able to get the connection to work and it does execute the first MySql query that is in the code below.  The rest of my code left shifts back to column 1 which means that when I get further down the code other mysql calls are not part of the with `SSHTunnelForwarder`.  Not surprisingly they fail.

1)Is the correct logic just to right shift the rest of the code over so it is all part of this `with` statement.   Or is there some other way to main and call this  tunnel forwarder?
2)This got me thinking, does this code create a new SSH tunnel with each mysql query?

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
     ('mysite.com', 22),
     ssh_pkey='open_ssh',
     ssh_username="root",
     remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)) as server:

   db = MySQLdb.connect(user='root',passwd='xxxx',db='db',host='127.0.0.1',port=server.local_bind_port)
   cursor = db.cursor() # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method

   cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_catagories where store='store' order by UpdateTime ASC")
   mysql_cats = cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shift that code right. You may want to put it all in a separate method.